# Resampling with and without replacement for estimating significance of spectral components

Tags: fourier, resampling

In order to test the significance of spectral components, it seems reasonable to randomly sort the data in order to destroy all the serial correlations / spectral order e.g. 100,000 times, and then estimate the significance or C.I.s by comparing your sample spectrum against the spectra of all the resorted data. Essentially H0 = there is no serial correlation / spectral order, and therefore the signal is white noise.

Here the resorted data would be resampling without replacement. My question is - is this correct or incorrect for spectral estimation? Would it be better to use resampling WITH replacement? And, if so, then why?

---

Thanks all for your responses! Indeed I am aware it is called bootstrapping - and just to clarify, my intention is not only to resort the time series 10,000 times, but to also create 10,000 spectra from these resorted versions of the time series in order to establish how many times my spectral component of interest is above the resorted time series spectra.

So H0 is that, over 10,000 comparisons, my spectral component is not higher in amplitude than the corresponding component in the resorted spectra more than 5% of the time. My H1 being that the spectral component is greater in amplitude (and therefore not due to chance) in at least 5% or more of the comparisons.

Indeed, I think you can go further than this and also calculate how many times it is BELOW the resorted time series spectra - this would, presumably, give you an indication of its persistence (i.e. it is more persistent than white noise and is therefore unlikely to change in a given period).

The code below calculates: the spectrum for a sine wave X[k] (length 30 time points), an average spectrum for the sine wave resampled 20000 times without replacement, an average spectrum for the sine wave resampled 20000 times with replacement. The original signal spectrum could as well be an average spectrum of, say, 200 signals of interest.

```
 Fs=1; %Sampling Frequency
 T=30; %Total signal duration in seconds
 t=0:(1./Fs):(T-(1./Fs)); %Time vector
 f1=1; % A frequency figure (in Hz)
 x=cos(f1*t);
 X=fft(x);
 X = abs(X);

 for i = 1:20000
     ps = round(rand(1,30)*29)+1;
     x_p_all(i,:)=(x(ps))';
     X_hat(i,:) = abs(fft(x_p_all(i,:)));
 end

 X_hat_mean = mean(X_hat);

 for i = 1: 20000
     ps2 = randperm(length(x));
     x_p_all2(i,:)=(x(ps2))';
     X_hat2(i,:) = abs(fft(x_p_all2(i,:)));;  
 end

 X_hat_mean2 = mean(X_hat2)

 plot(X_hat_mean)
 hold on
 plot(X)
 plot(X_hat_mean2)
```

[image: signal spectrum vs average noise spectra (with and without replacement)]

It can be seen that the resampling with replacement averages to be the same as the resampling without replacement average (as expected). Obviously, the energy of an individual resampled signal will be different for with and without replacement, but bootstrapping undertakes the process thousands of times. 
Now, if we don't permute and take the average, we have the option to compare our spectrum against each individual permutation, where each comparison would be a comparison like this:

[image: Signal spectrum vs spectrum of one single permutation of that signal]

Clearly, in this instance, the spectrum of the resampled signal (in this case, without replacement) looks far from white noise because it contains spurious periodicities as a result of the short time duration and limited number of frequency bins. My method compares these resampled signal spectra against the original signal spectrum e.g. 10,000 times to establish significance - a similar method to bootstrapping (which does not, as far as I am aware, require Bonferroni correction).

Answer (score 1):

> ...is this correct or incorrect for spectral estimation?

From what is provided in this description, I am more inclined to say that it is incorrect.

Here is my understanding of what you are describing:

You have some discrete time series $x[n]$ and its spectrum $X[k]$ which I will assume here that you obtained via the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) as $X = \mathcal{F}(x)$. $n$ denotes discrete time, $k$ denotes discrete frequency. Now, you pick some spectral component $X[k]$ and ask yourself: "Could this component have emerged by chance or is it really part of the signal?".

To answer this question, you shuffle $x[n]$ through a series of permutations that swap around some $n+u$ sample to $n+v$ sample. After shuffling a sufficiently long time, what you end up with is some $\hat{x}(n)$, accompanied by some $\hat{X}(k)$, which is essentially a white noise sequence *using the same values of $x(n)$*.

And then what? Where are the data for your $H_0$?

I am assuming that you are interested on the significance of some $X[k]$ (?).

If you create some **distribution of spectral components** from $\hat{X}(k)$, you could answer the question "Does $X[k]$ come from this distribution?". That is, could it be because of chance?

**BUT**, that would be equivalent to considering the average amplitude of a white noise sequence with equal *power* as your $x[n]$. Then, if $X[k]$ is above that average you can be sure that it cannot be due to noise.

*Ideally*, what you would like to have had is a distribution **for each X[k]**. That is, many realisations of the process that generates your signal, many realisations of their spectra and from all of these, one distribution for each $k$. Then, you could answer the question "Given the value of this $X[k]$, does it really come from my signal or not?"

If you are worried about the variance of the components, you might want to use [Welch's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method).

> Would it be better to use resampling WITH replacement?

That would modify the permutation rules to allow or disallow $u=v$. I don't see where is the re-sampling here. You had one spectrum before, you have one spectrum after the re-shuffling...Except if you mean that you would be storing each and every permutation result (?) in which case, yes, that would be wrong because it would represent the statistics of the deterioration process....Or maybe I am getting the whole thing wrong (?).

By the way, there is another thing you need to be careful of. If you did a number of statistical tests to test each and every spectral component then you would be assuming that spectral components are independent of each other and also you would have to correct your scores for repeated tests.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

A few notes with illustrations to understand better the problem and how to deal with it:

Let's build a signal to work with:

```
Fs=8000; %Sampling Frequency
T=4; %Total signal duration in seconds
t=0:(1./Fs):(T-(1./Fs)); %Time vector
p=2.*pi.*t; % Phase vector (These last two vectors save us typing the same things again and again).
f1=440; % A frequency figure (in Hz)
%
%
x=cos(f1.*p); %The signal
ps=randperm(length(x)); %A random permutation
x_p=x(ps); %The permuted signal
X = fft(x); % The spectrum of the signal
X_hat = fft(x(ps)); %The spectrum of the permuted signal
```

The key "objects of interest" here are `x` (the signal) and `ps` which is a permutation sequence. The permutation sequence will "loop" through the samples of `x` and re-map them to different time instances.

[Randperm](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/randperm.html) *samples WITHOUT replacement*. If you sample **WITH** replacement, then **the power of the permuted sequence will be different to the power of the non-permuted sequence** (see below). Even if you pass `x` through `ps` once, you will get a totally randomised `x` but you can try doing it a few times anyway.

Here are spectra of `x` and `x[ps[n]]` (i.e. `x` permuted once):

[image]

Here is the code that produces that graph:

```
subplot(221);plot(t,x);xlabel("Discrete time (s)");title("x[n]");grid;
subplot(222);plot(t,x_p);xlabel("Discrete Time (s)");title("Permuted x (x[ps[n]])");grid;
subplot(223);semilogy(Fs.*(0:length(x)-1)./length(x),(X.*conj(X))./(length(x).^2));grid;title("X[k]");xlabel("Discrete Frequency (Hz)");
subplot(224);semilogy(Fs.*(0:length(x)-1)./length(x),(X_hat.*conj(X_hat))./(length(x).^2));xlabel("Discrete Frequency (Hz)");title("Spectrum of permuted x[n]");grid
```

Notice the normalisation by `length(x)`. Also notice how `x` is permuted once by `x(ps)` which effects the "re-mapping".

Is the power of `x` different than the power of `x(ps)`. **No**, but only if you sample *without replacement*, in which case, each instantaneous value of `x` is re-used exactly once.

If you sample **with** replacement, some values of `x` might be **re-used** (re-map the same time instance twice), in which case the sum will work out to be different. You can try it with some other permutation sequence like `ps = round(rand(1,length(x)).*length(x));` which as you can see uses `rand` which doesn't care about its "history" of random values produced.

Here is the first thing that I am trying to say / clarify from what you are writing:

[image]

If you pick one `X[k]` and compare it against $\hat{X}$ *which is the whole spectrum of the permuted sequence* (fig above), then:

1. What you would really be asking would be "Can this component have risen by chance *from a random sequence with equal power as my `x`?*". Irrespectively of whether that bottom right spectrum is the result of one permutation or more it will be the spectrum of white noise of a sequence of power equal to that of `x`. Then, why go to the trouble of permuting `x` a few times? What is the added value? What is the power of `x`? The power of x is `sum(x.^2)`. What is the average power? The average power is `sum(x.^2)./length(x)`. How many points are there in the FFT? There are `length(x)` points. What is the sort of power we expect each bin to take? `(sum(x.^2)./length(x))/length(x) = sum(x.^2)./(length(x).^2)`. This is what the bottom two graphs depict (adjusted for one / two sided spectra, so, basically, each line divided by two).

This is why I am writing above, if you want to proceed this way, then you can simply say, the closer my spectral line gets to that "theoretical" average white noise value, the less I can be sure that it is due to signal.

2. You mention confidence intervals. If you proceed with the above frame of mind, you would be putting confidence intervals **on spectral lines** obtained by a distribution **across** the spectrum. In other words, you would put confidence intervals on $\pm X[k]$ from $\hat{X}$ (?). If you want to put confidence intervals on $X[k]$, you need to look **within** $X[k]$. In other words, put confidence intervals on the variation of $X[k]$ itself. How can you do this? Instead of deriving your $X$ from $x$, you derive it from successive overlapping frames obtained by $x$. In this way, you form $X_0[k], X_1[k], X_2[k], X_m[k]$ where $m$ is the $m^{th}$ frame and $k$ is the discrete frequency component. So, now, combined with the assumption that $x$ is Gaussian and that the power is squaring a Gaussian therefore the distribution will be Chi squared (the DFT is linear so no further changes), you can put confidence intervals from a Chi-square distribution with the degrees of freedom equal to the number of frames minus one. (Which, by the way, is the way [pwelch](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html) does it and why I am hinting at Welch's method above).

That is all I am trying to say.

With 30 time instances, you might be able to average "across subjects" (?). So, if your study has 30 participants, you can derive the "normal" variation of each $X[k]$ from those. Then, for an **unknown** spectrum, you can use those distributions to judge if a specific harmonic is "expectable" there or not.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 2:**

The above code can be used to experiment further, especially with re-shuffling. In Octave (and possibly MATLAB too), you can apply the reshuffling more than once in two ways, either via `x(ps)(ps)(ps)(ps)(ps)` and so on, or `x(ps(ps(ps(ps(ps(ps(ps)))))))` which permutes the permutation of the permutation of the permutation [...] of x. I have a sneaking suspicion that the first way doesn't work in MATLAB (that is the `x(ps)(ps)...(ps)`. Of course, you can even do it with different permutation sequences every time too.

Comment: This one will be more applied but you need to have access to Jstor. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2336278?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: My apologies, but I am slightly confused as to what your suggestion for the correct way is? You refer to a 'deterioration', but each resort is entirely random (uniform pdf). I am only resorting multiple times in order to acquire a reliable averaged random spectrum against which to compare my spectral components. Are you a) saying that the easiest way to do this would be to compare it against a random process of the same energy? and b) that this is still incorrect?  If so, I agree that my method is more time consuming, but why does this make it incorrect?

Comment: P.S. My time series data are also very short - only 30 time points. A single white noise process of this length does not look very random!

Comment: @MattVowels 1)Additional explanation clearer than original.2)Shuffling will take any $x[n]$ and convert it to white noise.White noise has equal magnitude across all frequencies.Why do you have to go through all of this shuffling when you can simply divide the power of the signal to the number of components that you have and then compare their amplitude? 3) For Welch's method, you can put confidence intervals in [this way](https://www.vibrationresearch.com/public_pdf/StatisticalPropertiesOfRandomPSD.pdf)...

Comment: @MattVowels ...4) Testing multiple $X[k]$ has to be [adjusted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction). I would not trust it. It's invalid, the components are not independent. Can I please ask what is your data source (?) (in the time domain). 30 points (in time domain (?)) are very few anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your continued feedback on this! The data source is daily self-report social sciences data (weird application I know - its experimental!). Segmenting 30 data points really doesn't yield useful results, so I'm unable to use Welch's method. I presume that the motivation behind resampling WITH replacement would be to help guarantee that all the X[k]s are independent?

Comment: @MattVowels, please see updated response. I have a feeling that you may be "stuck" with a particular way of thinking without having made a full connection with what this way of thinking means for your signal processing. Yes, the $X[k]$ will be independent but you would still be testing across "untestable" items (i.e. One spectral line with the distribution of the whole spectrum). Plus of course, if you do this multiple times it has to be adjusted.

Comment: I feel like I agree and understand everything in your post - but it just doesn't seem applicable to my scenario, where the spectrum of the resampled signal does not resemble anything like white noise because the length of the signal is so short. I've updated my question so you can see my thought process. If I'm still missing something then please don't feel obliged to respond - I'm already very grateful for all of your input!

Comment: @MattVowels Thanks for letting me know, if you felt that this post helped you, you can upvote or accept it through the controls on the left. Beyond this, this (deciding if a spectral component is there really) is a subject that is of interest to me. So, I am not trying to "convince" you about what is "right" here, I feel that I am getting something out of the interaction as well. One thing that would help is writing down the problem so that it is clear what we say and what we mean.

Comment: @A_A good to hear I was not being too frustrating! I did upvote your input (twice actually!) and it says it was logged but that it won't show as I'm not of sufficient stature on here... I'd be interested to know if my recent question edit (with graphs etc.) shed any more light onto my confusion - it seems to me that my 30 time points limitation makes it difficult to implement exactly what you are suggesting?

Comment: @MattVowels Not at all, [constructive discussion is very enjoyable](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46990/artifacts-signal-conversion-from-float-to-integer/47005#47005). If you clicked on upvote twice, the second click undid the first. The 30 time points are a severe limitation indeed. Is there any other indication, from the experiment / collected data on the [SNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)?

Comment: @A_A Hah I just tried again - no idea what state the upvote is in now - it still doesn't register anything for me, and I just get a notification to say that its been recorded but won't show because of my low reputation. No indication of SNR - each individual filled out the 30 day questionnaire once (so 30 days of time points for each individual) and I have 266 individuals...

Comment: @MattVowels So basically you are DFTing a rating scale? Like DFT on "How is your mood today" and then check for "robust" cycles across your subjects (?). Then why don't you take each scale (let's call it $x_{u,v}[n]$ for the $u^{th}$ subject, $v^{th}$ scale) and test $x$ for randomness? (Instead of testing the spectrum). Then, the $k^{th}$ component of the DFT explains the variance in $x$. **If** not random, then only a few components will be explaining the variation. The rest will be blending to the background "line" that is white noise.

Comment: @A_A yep that's right!  I'm also thinking more about this interdependence issue and Bonferroni - if I have a really high (high for the sake of demonstrating this argument, but really, the level doesn't matter) spectral peak, then this peak will contribute 'energy' to neighboring peaks via the limitations of the window and number of data points. If I have, say, 15 frequency bins, does this mean I should divide my alpha level by 15? So 0.05 becomes 0.0033? i.e. if a peak is above the level of white noise 99.67% of the time, THEN it is significant (rather tan 95% of the time).

Answer (score 0):

@Matt:  In the statistical world, what you are doing is called bootstrapping. You need to sample with replacement so that the distribution converges to the true distribution (under the null of independence ).  There is a ton of literature on bootstrapping ( Efron, 79, I think ) so I won't try to explain it but what you are doing seems reasonable to me. I would google for applied related papers. Below is relevant but it's from Annals so probably pretty theoretical-non applied.

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176348515

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. Do you think you can expand a little bit on what the OP is asking to see how bootstrapping is relevant to this question with the data it provides? We are talking about what is mentioned here specifically, that is, shuffling $x[n]$ and using the shuffled sequence for statistical testing. Not bringing in surrogate data. I don't see where is the "population" here to apply the bootstrapping to. Where are you going to randomly sample from?

Comment: Hi: Not a lot room here. Take an  AR(1). you construct an. AR(1) model and can't test for significance of coefficient  ( say $\phi$ ) because underlying distribution is not known. So, take the original observations and sample with replacement (so that you have the same # of observations )  and estimate the same AR(1). do that again, and again, then you have many estimates of $\phi$. to estimate it's  distribution . then, find where the actual estimate falls in the estimated distribution. if it's in the tails, that supports significance. google "intro to boostrapping" for clearer explanation.

Comment: Note that although above was just in time domain, the same "concept" appliues any time you want to test for significance.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am not convinced that it applies entirely here. What do you train the AR(1) on? Random values of $x[n]$? And then, how does it work for spectral estimation and how is this different from a straightforward test using the average power of a noise sequence (?). These are the points I do not get from this answer.

Comment: Hi: You estimate the AR(1) over and over on the shuffled (with replacement) observations. This will give you the distribution of the phi estimate under the null that there is no relationship.  Then you estimate phi using the actual ( not shuffled ) data and compare that estimate to the estimated distribution.  I'm pretty confident that it applies but  the details  definitely matter. When time allows,  I'll read his question again and see if I can be more specific. I may not be able to though because I may not be able to understand what he's doing exactly because I'm new to DSP.

Comment: in above, you re-shuffle each time you estimate. that may have not been clear in the explanation.

Comment: Hi: I read it again. What I don't understand is how shuffling will add value ? Yes, shuffling gets rid of autocorrelation ( or atleast attempts to ) in the time domain.  But, when one goes over to  the frequency domain, I'm not clear on what shuffling does. Does it modify the fourier coefficients so that they become more random and less significant ? If so, then bootstrapping should work there also but, instead of having $\phi$ as in my example, he has a set of fourier coefficients and each one can be tested against its estimated distribution under the null of independence. I hope this helps.

Comment: If anyone is reading this besides me ( LOL ) and could explain how randomly sampling the series with replacement to remove autocorrelation in the time domain, also makes the fourier coefficients more random and less significant, ( I'm assuming it does this based on OP's question )  it's appreciated. I don't see that. Autocorrelation is a time based measure and there is no time component in the frequency domain. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark, I believe power spectrum is the DFT of the autocorrelation. By re-sorting the data, you are destroying the serial correlation in the data. Each re-sort is likely to contain some spurious/random serial correlation, but over e.g. 10000 resorts this will be averaged out. The spectral components reflect periodicity (i.e. order/patterns) in the data, so again, by resorting, this is randomized. If you take a sine wave and randomize it 10,000 times and average all the resulting spectra, it will be white noise (which is ALL frequency components of equal amplitude). Does that help at all?

Comment: @Matt:  Now that you said it,  I think that I remember reading that the DFT of the autocorrs is the spectrum. So, you are saying that if you take the DFT of the autocorrelations, you get what ? Not the fourier coefficients associated with the series, right ? As far as you're averaging explanation, that makes sense. Even though a set of fourier coefficients might be significant, i I can see them averaging to zero which can be viewed as insignificant ? So, I kind of get it now except what do the fourier coefficients of the DFT of the autocorrelation represent ?

Comment: Yep DFT of the autocorrelation is the power spectrum (which is also the amplitude spectrum squared). Fourier said that any periodic signal can be represented as a sum of sines/cosines (in reality you can, of course, take the DFT of ANY signal, regardless of its inherent periodicity). So a single time-domain sine wave amplitude=1 would have a DFT of all zeros except for a complex coefficient (usually in a+jb form) describing the phase of the sine wave (tan^-1 b/a) and its amplitude (sqrt(a^2+b^2)). If a signal contained every possible sine wave at equal amplitude, it would be also considered...

Comment: ... white noise. The DFT coefficients wouldn't average to zero in the case of white noise, because zero would mean zero energy. A completely random process contains equal energy at ALL frequencies, and so no single frequency components would stand out amongst the others. This is where the test for significance comes in - "is the component of interest significantly higher in amplitude than those due to the white noise?"  Take the autocorrelation of a sine wave and take the DFT of this ACF, and you will see the power spectrum for a sine wave (a single spike at the frequency of the sine wave).

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. Will print out and read carefully. I sense lots of good wisdom in what you are saying and can learn from it.  It's much appreciated.